# Why async function objects get disappaer after first run?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am confused about async and await. to use an await, it should be in an async function, ok, but then how first one will start ?

I have a async function and it has awaits chain inside it. When I refresh it runs and I can see object values but later they disappear. getMyValues is my function and the problem is; when I debug, I can see objects and its values but its disappear when I want to use them later, only I can use strings I get from them, even they disappear sometimes.

So, I have few questions;
Q1) Why object become undefined ? I know javascript objects are dynamic, but I see issue even I make a deepclone. How does it happen same session works again and even that session object becomes undefined..

```
 async function getMyValues() {
 // Initialize a session. 
 var session = await myclass.createSession(5)
 var myValues = session.getValues()
```

I run like this;

```
     getMyValues()
```

Q2) If I put return inside that function and run like that I can see a promise in debug..How to return a value from these kind of functions properly ?

let myvals = getMyValues()

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not a good dupe target

Comment: @FrankerZ it's exactly correct. The last line of the question shows the fallacy of assuming you can externally treat the function as synchronous: `let myvals = getMyValues()`. OP wants to know how to "return the response from an asynchronous call"

Comment: what is the link for dublicate question ?

Answer (score 0):

Your function will essentially be rewritten to (assuming you return `myValues` from `getMyValues()`):

```
function getMyValues() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Initialize a session. 
        myclass.createSession(5)
            .then(session => {
                var myValues = session.getValues()
                resolve(myValues);
            });
    });
 }
```

Now, `getMyValues()` returns a **promise**, so you need to handle that asyncronously as well. (Either with `.then()` or with `await` on that function:

```
getMyValues().then(values => {
    console.log('All the boys in the yard like these values: ', values);
});
```